# Sorting a dictionary by values, using a class-provided sort key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, lambda

I'm using a class with multiple members.  This class offers a method which returns a sort key: a tuple defining how instances should be sorted.  I have a dictionary where the values are instances of this class, indexed by an integer identifier.

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    
    def sort_key(self):
        return (self.name, self.age)
    
unsorted = {
    111: Dog('Molly', 3),
    112: Dog('Sammy', 5),
    113: Dog('Leo', 4),
    114: Dog('Sammy', 3)    
}
```

Using Python 3.6+ (where dictionary order is preserved), I'd like to create a dictionary sorted by the value's class method.  My attempt uses a lambda on `items()` to generate (key, value) tuples, from which I attempt to call the value's `sort_key()` method:

```
# GOAL: sort by name and then age, to produce dictionary with keys ordered 113, 111, 114, 112

result = {k: unsorted[k] for k in sorted(unsorted.items(), key=lambda i: i[1].sort_key())}
```

This raises a `KeyError`.  The issue seems to be not with my `sorted` call, but my dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that `sorted()` was not returning the key but instead a `(key, value)` tuple (which, in hindsight, makes more sense).

The following achieved my goal:

```
result = {i[0]: i[1] for i in sorted(unsorted.items(), key=lambda i: i[1].sort_key())}
```